# Can gitolite repo name be Chinese or other language but not English

Tags: git, repository

All the tests are on

- Windows8 x64
- msysgit 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0
- gitolite 3.5

After I add a repo in gitolite.conf:

```
repo 中文
    RW+     =   @admin
```

After I commit, the push operation success, but with improper line.

```
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 343 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: FATAL: bad reponame 'ÖÐÎÄ'
To git@financeserver.landi.landicorp.com:gitolite-admin
   409ac7a..17fa9bb  master -> master
```

Please note the line:

```
remote: FATAL: bad reponame 'ÖÐÎÄ'
```

When I clone the gitolite-admin project, I can see the push is successful.

But when I clone the repo with Chinese name in git bash, It will fail.

```
$ git clone financeserver:中文

Cloning into '中文'...
FATAL: invalid repo name: '中文'
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I can make sure I hava access rights to any Non-Chinese repo.

Is there a solution to add a repo with Chinese name? Thx.

Comment: can you post that repo's address?

Comment: Sorry, the server is inside the company. And I've omit something. When I add a repo with Chinese in gitolite, the push operation failed. I've updated the question.

Comment: What OS are you running git on? If Windows, which git are you running?

Comment: I'm on Windows8 x64 and msysgit 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0